# Grep for beginning of line while searching for a certain string

Tags: bash, loops

I have a file like such:

```
1    Role A
2    Role b
```

What I'd like to do is search for the String "Role A" and return the value 1 in a variable.

So something like the following:

```
if grep "$i" role_info.txt
then
    <assign a variable the number associated with the string>
else
    <no search string found - do something else>
fi
```

Comment: Do you want it for each line from the file or just one search per file?

Comment: There will only be one matching search string, so it will always be just one line that is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns are delimited with tabs then you can do:

```
role='Role A'
number=$(awk -v role="$role" -F '\t' '$2==role {print $1}' role_info.txt)
```

If it's just spaces, try instead:

```
role='Role A'
number=$(grep "$role" role_info.txt | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

Either way, you can then check if a match was found with:

```
if [[ -n $number ]]; then
    # number found
else
    # not found
fi
```

Another option is:

```
while read number role; do
    if [[ $role == 'Role A' ]]; then
        # match found
    fi
done < role_info.txt
```

This will be a bit more robust: the role has to be the second item on the line; it can't be in first position.

Answer (score 0):

I use awk for this.  Can I assume there's a tab between the number and the rolename column?  If so,

```
awk -F'\t' '$2 == "Role A" {print $1}' role_info.txt
```

To take the pattern you're searching for from a shell variable gets a little tricky, because you're mixing shell variables and awk columns, but it can be done:

```
pat="Role A"
awk -F'\t' "\$2 == \"$pat\" {print \$1}" role_info.txt
```

Finally, to assign the result to another shell variable:

```
result=`awk -F'\t' "\\$2 == \"$pat\" {print \\$1}" role_info.txt`
```

(In this last case you need to double some of the backslashes inside ``.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the the simple way:

```
role=$(grep "Role A" foo.txt | awk '{print $1}')
```

Then to check if the role has been assigned, check if it's not empty like:

```
if [ ! -z "$role" ]; then
  echo "Role exist"
else
  echo "Role does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
read -a num <<< $(grep "Role A" role_info.txt) && echo ${num[0]}
```

Here `num` is an array, and `${num[0]}` contains `1`

Or this:

```
read num dummy <<< $(grep "Role A" role_info.txt) && echo $num
```

Here `num` contains `1`

If no matches found, the variable `num` will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

grep "Role A" role_info.txt >> /dev/null && var=1

You can use var value to decide.

Comment: Please add more explanation to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple sed oneliner?

```
res=$(sed -ne "s/^\([0-9]\+\)[[:space:]]\+${i}/\1/p" role_info.txt)
[[ -z $res ]] && { <do something else>; }
```

#### How it works

The regular expression looks for a line like this:

> [beginning of line][a number][at least 1 whitespace][value of variable i]

- The number may have multiple digits.  0-leading numbers are also allowed.
- The braces around the variable is redundant in this case, but I put it in case you want to switch to using something like an array in the future.

If there is a match, it is stored in the variable `res`.  No match leads to an empty variable.  The second line checks if the contents of `res` is of 0-length, if the compound command (the stuff inside braces) is executed.  Please note, single line compound commands require you the have a space after the opening brace, and one before the closing brace.  This is necessary to distinguish from brace expansion.  Of course you can always break it into a multi-line command.

**Note**: The sed command needs to be in double quotes to allow for variable substitution.  You should be careful not to pass quotes.